# MySQL CONCAT_WS from many variables - how can I limit the query to merely existing data?

Tags: mysql, concat-ws

I have been looking through all other mentionings of "MySQL" and "CONCAT_WS" but they do not address my problem. I have a medical database set up in MySQL (5.5.6x) with 180 tables and several thousand fields. The handling of database tables and forms is done through a large PHP application.

Part of my SQL query is the following code:

```
    CONCAT_WS(""
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff1 = "2" THEN "Cholezystektomie  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff2 = "2" THEN "Appendektomie  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff3 = "2" THEN "Adhäsiolyse  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff4 = "2" THEN "Antrum-Resektion  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff5 = "2" THEN "Hiatoplastie  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff6 = "2" THEN "Hernien-Reparatur  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff7 = "2" THEN "Band-Entfernung  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff8 = "2" THEN "Fundus-Resektion  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff9 = "2" THEN "Rest-Gastrektomie  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff10 = "2" THEN "Leber-Biopsie  " ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        , COALESCE(CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff99 = "2" THEN "Andere Begleiteingriffe" ELSE CONCAT("", "") END, "NULL")
        ) AS "Begleiteingriffe (OP 5)",
```

This denotes the content extraction of the fields

```
    op.OP5Begleiteingriffx = "2"
```

(`= "2"` means that the respective checkbox has been clicked) from x equalling -1 to -10 or -99.

**Now, I want to limit the display of results to those fields which are not empty.**

**Is there an elegant way to do this in a short fashion?**

So far, I have implemented something like this:

```
    FROM dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users_benutzer ub ON ub.ID = p.UserID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "1950-01-01" AND "2050-12-31"
    AND (
        "Begleiteingriffe (OP 1)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 2)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 3)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 4)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 5)" != ""
        )
    ORDER BY p.Nachname, p.Vorname, p.Gebdatum; ';
```

It still delivers ALL results and does not omit the empty fields:

[image: The green arrows indicate the column where op.OP5Begleiteingriffx is being displayed]

Is it possible at all to handle it this way or do I need to set up a handling for every

```
    op.OP5Begleiteingriffx
```

like in the above-mentioned `AND ...` statement?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're asking but given that `CONCAT_WS` ignores `NULL` values perhaps something like `CONCAT_WS("  ", CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff1 = "2" THEN "Cholezystektomie" END, CASE WHEN op.OP5Begleiteingriff2 = "2" THEN "Appendektomie" END, ...) AS \`Begleiteingriffe (OP 5)\``?

Comment: Usually, this type of question can easily attract people to help.. unfortunately, there are just queries without any example data provided for others to replicate the situation.

Comment: I will try your recommendation, Nick, thank you; tcadiddot0, fair enough, I have enclosed a screenshot of the results.

Comment: Sorry, tcadidot0, for misspelling your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWN SOLUTION:

It does not work regarding the use of

```
    "Begleiteingriffe (OP 1)" != ""
```

or

```
    "Begleiteingriffe (OP 1)" IS NOT NULL
```

but works when every single possibility is handled as such in

```
    WHERE (
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff1 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff2 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff3 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff4 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff5 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff6 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff7 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff8 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff9 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff10 = "2" OR
        op.OP1Begleiteingriff99 = "2"
    )
```

Now, I only get displayed results where there are no more empty fields:

[image: The green arrow now shows the same column with non-empty fields only]

Answer (score 1):

I think, instead of doing bunch of `OR` in `WHERE`, you might try using `HAVING`. Probably, something like this:

```
SELECT  ....
       .....
FROM dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users_benutzer ub ON ub.ID = p.UserID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "1950-01-01" AND "2050-12-31"
--remove this part
/*    AND (
        "Begleiteingriffe (OP 1)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 2)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 3)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 4)" != "" OR "Begleiteingriffe (OP 5)" != ""     ) */
-- add HAVING here
HAVING "Begleiteingriffe (OP 1)" <> ""
    ORDER BY p.Nachname, p.Vorname, p.Gebdatum; ';
```

Try if this can work.

Comment: Yes, that works as well, thank you very much. My own answer is much more simple-minded and, thus, longer and more clumsy.